# Riak with Search On Dropping Indexes on Restore

Tags: solr, riak, yokozuna

I'm attempting to restore Riak onto a new instance (single node, no ring). I rename the node and update the configurations using the `riak-admin reip` command. However, when I start Riak and once Yokozuna starts, Yokozuna drops the indexes that have been restored in the `yz` directory. Here is what I see in the logs: 
`2017-12-05 23:01:00.130 [info] <0.3554.0>@riak_kv_index_hashtree:build_or_rehash:1055 Starting AAE tree build: 91343852333181432387730302044767688728495783936
2017-12-05 23:01:11.030 [info] <0.3396.0>@yz_events:sync_indexes:263 Delta: Removed: [<<"audit">>,<<"default">>,<<"finder">>] Added: [] Same: []
2017-12-05 23:01:11.124 [info] <0.3396.0>@yz_index:local_remove:315 Unloaded previous instance of index audit
2017-12-05 23:01:11.158 [info] <0.3396.0>@yz_index:local_remove:315 Unloaded previous instance of index default
2017-12-05 23:01:11.205 [info] <0.3396.0>@yz_index:local_remove:315 Unloaded previous instance of index finder`


Any idea how to prevent this from occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was missing the cluster_data directory. I needed that to able to restore the data with the indexes.